# No supported files were found in the directory

Tags: prettier

Directory:

[image]

`.prettierignore`

```
# Ignore artifacts:
# Ignore artifacts:
.prettierignore
node_modules
build/
dist/
package.json
src/static/fonts/**
src/static/images/**
src/static/svg/**
yarn.lock
```

Abnormal screenshot:

[image]

Please tell me how to ignore several directories.

Comment: Try removing `**` after `fonts/`.

Comment: Besides removing ```**``` check your ignore file is in the root of your project. You can also exclude specific file types as such: ```**/*.jpg```